# How to Set the Background Color of a Text Area Inside of a Scroll Pane?

Tags: java, user-interface, text, colors, javafx

I'm working on a PI approximation(using the infinite series) GUI, and I've run into a strange problem. In the JavaFX8 Scene Builder I set the background color to `-fx-background-color: black;` but when I start the program, the background is still white. The strange thing I've noticed is that the outline of the TextArea has turned black though. I've already checked for contradicting code that turns the background white again, but since I just started there can't be any. Stranger yet, the TextArea appears black in the preview of the program in the scene builder. The node graph can be seen in the first picture on the left.

EDIT:
FXML(In this text file, I couldn't figure out how to post the code. I tried the blockquote, posting it normally, and trying the code literal tags): https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ic6n1vbsqqu7pg/FXML.txt

Text Area In Scene Builder:
[image: Text Area In Scene Builder]
Text Area Running:
[image: Text Area Running]

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the FXML/CSS so that somebody can replicate it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, a couple of years late..

```
.text-area .content 
{
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```